# I am unable to solve the security exception regarding permission of BIND_WALLPAPER

Tags: android, android-manifest, live-wallpaper

I have spent so much time for solving the issue regarding the permission of BIND_WALLPAPER in my application.But I was unable to solve it.I am not getting where to give the permission.Please tell me where i committed mistake.Please help me.I am getting exception like this.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=.BloobaForeground cmp=pl.miniti.android.blooba/.BloobaForeground } from ProcessRecord{40b1fd70 15485:pl.miniti.android.blooba/10106} (pid=15485, uid=10106) requires android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER
```

and my manifest file is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pl.miniti.android.blooba"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:description="@string/app_description"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service
        android:name=".BloobaService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/blooba" />
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".BloobaSettings"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/blooba_settings"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BloobaForeground"
        android:label="@string/select_foreground"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".BloobaForeground" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                 />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BloobaBackground"
        android:label="@string/select_background"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".BloobaBackground" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
```

to the `<service android:name=".BloobaService"` and any other other `WallpaperService` that you have

Comment: I am getting the same exception even after adding the permission in service

Comment: Remove the permission from all the other tags except the `Service`

Comment: i got it.But my live wall paper got some deviations.It is totally changed.

Comment: i.e When i am changing my foreground,the foreground image got shaked